# Scrapy - yield nested dictionary to JSON file - doesn't work

Tags: python, json, dictionary, scrapy, scrapy-item

**EDIT**

As Georgiy suggested, I tried to yield `dict` instead of `Item` and the results are the same.

**EDIT END**

Trying to export Scrapy output to a JSON file. An item should have this format:

```
{'name':'Peter', 'attrs':{'attr1':<VAL>, 'attr2':<VAL>}}
```

The problem is that Scrapy renders `name` only. The reason is probably that `attrs` is a dictionary.

```
class CookieBotItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    attrs = scrapy.Field()
```

For the simplicity I return always this:

```
    yield CookieBotItem(name='Peter',
                        attrs={
                            'attr1': 'val1',
                            'attr2': 'val2'}
                        )
```

And the ouput looks like this:

```
[
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"},
{"name": "Peter"}
]
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about usage of Item classes here for this.. nested items.
The fastest way to achieve this is to `yield` dictionaries (not Item class objects):

```
    yield {
           'name': 'Peter',
           'attrs':{'attr1': 'val1','attr2': 'val2'}
          }
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried it and, unfortunatelly, it gives me the same result. I'm running this command: `scrapy crawl spider -a filepath=someval -o out.json`

Comment: Exported fields can be limited by `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` setting.  Does your project have it enabled?

Comment: OMG, yes, I forgot that I've set this setting... it works now, thank you